# Haskell trying to mutate string in [String]

Tags: haskell

```
movex [] a s = []    
movex (x:xs) a s
| elem a x = moveNow x a s
| otherwise = x : (movex xs a s)
where
  moveNow x a s
    | s == 'l' = moveNow2 x a
    where
        moveNow2 [] _ = []
        moveNow2 (x:y:xs) a
          | x == ' ' && y == a = a : x : moveNow2 (y:xs) a
          | otherwise = x : moveNow2 (y:xs) a
```

<- This is what I got right now

I am trying to make a function that iterates through [string], finds the right string and then mutates it.

given input

```
func ["abc", "dfg"] f l -- move f in this list 1 space left --
```

expected output

```
["abc", "fdg"]
```

Right now I am stuck at movex function that gives me error

```
Couldn't match expected type `Char' with actual type `[Char]'
In the first argument of `(:)', namely `x'
In the expression: x : (movex xs a s)
```

Comment: `| elem a x = moveNow x a s` but what about xs? How can you drop it? Perhaps try giving your functions explicit type signatures.

Comment: what is the use of this condition `x==' '` ?

Comment: use for condition `x==' '` is to check whether x is a space character or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Direct solution to the error is to replace the line

```
| elem a x = moveNow x a s
```

With

```
| elem a x = moveNow x a s : movex xs a s
```

Or, probably

```
| elem a x = moveNow x a s : xs
```

Depending on what you want to do after the first match: continue looking for certain character, or leave other strings untouched.

Your `moveNow` function has return type `String`, or `[Char]`, while `movex` has `[String]`, or `[[Char]]`, that's why compiler complains.

To avoid such problems(or fix them easier) consider writing explicit type signatures, like so:

```
movex :: [String]->String->String->[String]
```

Comment: Replacing with `| elem a x = moveNow x a s : xs` is what I was after. Thanks!